# convert ternary operator to if else

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have this ternary operator which i am trying to understand by converting it to normal `ifelse`

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()]) ? $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] + 1 : 1;
```

but I am not getting the correct result

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";
if (isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()])) {
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] + 1;
}else{
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = 1;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: In doing `$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";`, you're creating  a condition that means `if (isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()])) {` will always be true.... you're ensuring that it is created before testing whetherit exists....  get rid of the `$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";` line

Comment: ah, thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doing

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";
```

you're creating  a condition that means

```
if (isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()])) {
```

will always be true.... you're ensuring that it is created before testing whether it exists, so (of course) it will always exist.

Get rid of the

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";
```

line

---

You can also simplify

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] + 1;
```

to

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()]++;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The ternary can simply be translated to

```
if(isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()]))
{
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] + 1;
}
else
{
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove first line

```
$countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = "";
```

Correct way is

```
if (isset($countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()])) {
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] + 1;
}else{
    $countDinner[$invitation->getDinner()->getId()] = 1;
}
```